# Transverse part of a current

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism

I am reading Many particle physics (3rd edition by Mahan). On page 51, there is a current of the form $$\vec{j}(\vec{r})=\vec{J}_0e^{i\vec{k}\cdot\vec{r}}$$, the transverse part of it is: $$\vec{j}_t=-\frac{1}{k^2}\vec{k}\times(\vec{k}\times\vec{J}_0)e^{i\vec{k}\cdot\vec{r}}$$

I can easily obtain this by using the total part minus the perpendicular part, which is:
$$\vec{j}_t=\vec{j}-(\vec{j}\cdot\vec{k})\vec{k}/k^2$$

However, the book gives a definition of a more general form of the transverse current:
$$\vec{j}_t(\vec{r}):= \frac{1}{4\pi}\nabla\times(\nabla\times\int d^3r'\frac{\vec{j}(\vec{r}')}{|\vec{r}-\vec{r}'|})=\vec{j}(\vec{r})+\frac{1}{4\pi}\nabla(\nabla\cdot\int d^3r'\frac{\vec{j}(\vec{r}')}{|\vec{r}-\vec{r}'|})$$

In the last equal sign the definition of Dirac delta is used.

I want to show the last term in third line and fourth line are equal, but I can't proceed the last term, any one please guide me how can I simplify this?

Comment: What exactly do you need help with? You want to see how the last equality is true or you want to see how your third line is the same as your fourth line (it isn't, your fourth line is the spatial fourier transform of your third line)? If it is the first one, have you considered [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_calculus_identities#Curl_of_the_curl) identity?

Comment: @NowIGetToLearnWhatAHeadIs Yes, I need to see the equivalence of third and forth line. By the way, third and fourth are not related by fourier transform. Both of them are in real space.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer this question, I will first give my own definition of the transverse current, and then I will show how both of your formulas agree with this new definition of transverse current.

## My definition

For any current $\vec{j}(\vec{r})$, I define the transverse current $\vec{j}_t (r)$, which is a functional of the current, $\vec{j}_t=\vec{j}_t[\vec{j}]$, by the following algorithm. To get $\vec{j}_t$ from $\vec{j}$, you take the fourier transform $\tilde{\vec{j}}(\vec{k})$ of $\vec{j}(\vec{r})$, and you form a new spectrum by projecting $\tilde{\vec{j}}(\vec{k})$ onto the plane orthogonal to $\vec{k}$ at each point $\vec{k}$ : $$\tilde{\vec{j}}_t(\vec{k}) = (\mathbb{1} - \hat{k} \otimes \hat{k})\tilde{\vec{j}}(\vec{k}) =\tilde{\vec{j}}(\vec{k}) - (\hat{k} \cdot\tilde{\vec{j}}(\vec{k}) )\hat{k} =\tilde{\vec{j}}(\vec{k})- (\vec{k} \cdot\tilde{\vec{j}}(\vec{k}) )\vec{k} /k^2. $$
Once this is done, the transverse current $\vec{j}_t(\vec{r})$ is defined as the inverse fourier transform of $\tilde{\vec{j}}_t(\vec{k})$.

So why is it called the transverse current? It is called the transverse current because in reciprocal space, the transverse current $\tilde{\vec{j}}_t$ is just the part of the current $\tilde{\vec{j}}$ which is transverse (that is to say perpendicular) to the wavevector $\vec{k}$ (at each wavevector $\vec{k}$).

## Your formula 3

For your formula 3, you assume that you start with current $\vec{j}$ of the form $\vec{j}(\vec{r}) = \vec{J}_0e^{i\vec{k}_0\cdot\vec{r}}$. Then the fourier transform of $\vec{j}$ is $\tilde{\vec{j}}(\vec{k}) = \vec{J}_0\delta^3(\vec{k}-\vec{k}_0) $. Then the fourier transform of the transverse current $\tilde{\vec{j}}_t$ is

\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
\tilde{\vec{j}}_t(\vec{k})&=\tilde{\vec{j}}(\vec{k})- (\vec{k} \cdot\tilde{\vec{j}}(\vec{k}) )\vec{k} /k^2\\
 &= \vec{J}_0\delta^3(\vec{k}-\vec{k}_0)- (\vec{k} \cdot\vec{J}_0\delta^3(\vec{k}-\vec{k}_0) )\vec{k} /k^2\\
&=(\vec{J}_0- (\vec{k} \cdot\vec{J}_0)\vec{k} /k^2)\delta^3(\vec{k}-\vec{k}_0)\\
&=(\vec{J}_0- (\vec{k}_0 \cdot\vec{J}_0)\vec{k}_0 /k_0^2)\delta^3(\vec{k}-\vec{k}_0)
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
The transverse current in real (i.e. non-reciprocal) space is the inverse fourier transform of this $\tilde{\vec{j}}_t(\vec{k})$. Thus the current is given by 
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
\vec{j}_t(\vec{r}) &= (\vec{J}_0- (\vec{k}_0 \cdot\vec{J}_0)\vec{k}_0 /k_0^2)e^{i \vec{k}_0 \cdot \vec{r}}\\
&= \vec{J}_0e^{i \vec{k}_0 \cdot \vec{r}}- (\vec{k}_0 \cdot\vec{J}_0e^{i \vec{k}_0 \cdot \vec{r}})\vec{k}_0 /k_0^2\\
&= \vec{j}(\vec{r})- (\vec{k}_0 \cdot\vec{j}(\vec{r}))\vec{k}_0 /k_0^2
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
Thus we have recovered your third formula.

## Your formula 4

Now suppose we have an arbitrary $\vec{j}$. What is the real space formula for $\vec{j}_t$? One way of getting the formula is just to use the rule $\vec{k} \to -i \vec{\nabla}$ on my definition and then remember that $\nabla^{-2} \vec{A}(\vec{r}) = \frac{-1}{4 \pi} \int \frac{\vec{A}(\vec{r}')}{|\vec{r} - \vec{r}'|} d\vec{r}'$. This immediately gives your expression from the first displayed equation in this answer.

A more rigorous approach is to check that your fourth equation gives the right answer (according to my definition) when applied to plane wave currents. Then by linearity, it must give the correct answer when applied to arbitrary currents, since any arbitrary current can be written as a sum of plane waves, and both your fourth equation and my definition are linear in the current.

So let's assume a current of the form $\vec{j}(\vec{r}) = \vec{J}_0e^{i\vec{k}_0\cdot\vec{r}}$.

First we must compute $\int d^3r'\frac{\vec{j}(\vec{r}')}{|\vec{r}-\vec{r}'|}$. We will use the fact that $\nabla^2 \int d^3r'\frac{\vec{j}(\vec{r}')}{|\vec{r}-\vec{r}'|} = - 4 \pi \vec{j}(\vec{r})$. Thus the integral operator $\int d^3r'\frac{1}{|\vec{r}-\vec{r}'|}\cdot$ is $-4 \pi$ times the inverse operator of $\nabla^2$. Then since $\nabla^2$ takes $e^{i \vec{k}_0 \cdot \vec{r}}$ to $-k_0^2 e^{i \vec{k}_0 \cdot \vec{r}}$, we must have that $\int d^3r'\frac{e^{i \vec{k}_0 \cdot \vec{r}}}{|\vec{r}-\vec{r}'|} = \frac{4 \pi}{k_0^2}e^{i \vec{k}_0 \cdot \vec{r}}.$ Thus we find that 
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
\int d^3r'\frac{\vec{j}(\vec{r}')}{|\vec{r}-\vec{r}'|} &= \int d^3r'\frac{\vec{J}_0e^{i\vec{k}_0\cdot\vec{r}}}{|\vec{r}-\vec{r}'|} \\
&=\frac{4 \pi}{k_0^2}\vec{J}_0e^{i \vec{k}_0 \cdot \vec{r}}
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

Next we must compute 
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
\frac{1}{4\pi}\nabla(\nabla\cdot \frac{4 \pi}{k_0^2}\vec{J}_0e^{i \vec{k}_0 \cdot \vec{r}}) &= \nabla(\nabla\cdot \frac{1}{k_0^2}\vec{J}_0e^{i \vec{k}_0 \cdot \vec{r}}) \\
&=\frac{1}{k_0^2} \nabla(\nabla\cdot \vec{J}_0e^{i \vec{k}_0 \cdot \vec{r}})\\
&=\frac{1}{k_0^2}\nabla(i \vec{k}_0\cdot \vec{J}_0e^{i \vec{k}_0 \cdot \vec{r}}) \\
&=\frac{1}{k_0^2}(i \vec{k}_0)(i \vec{k}_0\cdot \vec{J}_0e^{i \vec{k}_0 \cdot \vec{r}})\\
&= - \vec{k}_0( \vec{k}_0\cdot \vec{J}_0e^{i \vec{k}_0 \cdot \vec{r}})/k_0^2 \\
&= - \vec{k}_0( \vec{k}_0\cdot \vec{j}(\vec{r}))/k_0^2 
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

Thus for plane wave currents $\vec{j}(\vec{r})+\frac{1}{4\pi}\nabla(\nabla\cdot\int d^3r'\frac{\vec{j}(\vec{r})}{|\vec{r}-\vec{r}'|}) = \vec{j}-(\vec{j}\cdot\vec{k}_0)\vec{k}_0/k_0^2$, and so your equation four gives the same expression for the transverse current of a plane wave as your equation three, and so it agrees too with my definition. By linearity, your equation four must agree with my definition for all currents $\vec{j}(\vec{r})$.

## Conclusion

Hopefully from my definition of transverse current you have a better intuition for what the transverse current means. Also you can see how your formulas three and four fit in with this idea.

Comment: Thanks so much for your detailed and beautiful proofs. So according to my understanding, both the definition of yours and my eqn 4  of the transverse current is in the most general form, even if we are considering the non-homogeneous system such as crystals.

Comment: And will you please explain more on your first paragraph under the title **Your formula 4** ? I would like to see how you can get the general transverse current using your definition.

Comment: I think I've understand that paragraph. Using your definition, first I calculate the fourier component of that general current, $j_t(k)$, then do a inverse fourier transform I will get back to my eqn. 4.

Comment: yes that is right. The formula in my definition is basically just the fourier transform of your formula four. So to use my definition your fourier transform the current, then use the formula in my definition, then do an inverse fourier transform.